# CSS rotation. Rotate div but stay in exactly the same coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm just playing around with a little javascript game, building a pacman game. You can see it here: http://codepen.io/acha5066/pen/rOyaPW

I'm having an issue with the rotation though. You can see if you play around with it that when pac rotates, he points in a different direction but his coordinates also change a bit. What should happen is he should rotate but be in exactly the same spot.

I'm using `transform-origin: 'center center';` but I also tried it with `transform-origin: 'top left';` however neither give me what I want.

Comment: give your container a width http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpWpBp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give your container a width or the `transform-origin: x` won't have any effect (the center of 0 is still 0).

```
.pac-man {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 60px;
}
```

[updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpWpBp)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your pacman class does not have a width and height. If you add

```
.pac-man {
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

it will work.